# Join on column and return null values - MS access

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I have two tables:

Table Cars:

```
RegNr      Sold
-------   ------
ABC123    2015-12-27
ABC222   
ABC333    
ABC444
```

table Unit:

```
VIN       BuyerPayed
------    ----------
ABC123    2015-12-18
ABC222    2015-12-18
ABC333    NULL
ABC444    2015-12-19
```

I see that ABC222 and ABC444 has recieved payment from the Buyer, so I want to  have a SELECT statement that finds ABC222 ABC444.

I have tried

```
Select cars.regnr, cars.sold, Unit.BuyerPayedDate from Unit Inner Join cars on cars.regnr= unit.vin where cars.sold is Null and Unit.BuyerPayed is Not Null;
```

but I get some awkward result.

Help please.

Comment: Actually I want to FIND the rows in need of an update: so I've tried this: Select cars.regnr, cars.sold, Unit.BuyerPayed from tUnit Inner Join cars on cars.regnr = unit.vin where cars.sold is Null and Unit.BuyerPayed is Not Null; But it returns something awkward...

Comment: Please update your question with details about what you have tried and what doesn't work.

Comment: that query you've written works for me, what do you mean with awkward?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an UPDATE query with a join:

```
update
  cars inner join unit on cars.RegNr = unit.VIN
set
  cars.Sold = unit.BuyerPayed
```

and (depending on the logic you want to implement) you might want to add this condition:

```
where
  cars.Sold IS NULL
```

this will update cars `ABC222` and `ABC444` but not `ABC123` because it already has a Sold date.

If, instead of updating the table, you just want to SELECT the rows that need an update you can use this query:

```
select cars.RegNr
from
  cars inner join unit on cars.RegNr = unit.VIN
where
  cars.Sold IS NULL
  and unit.BuyerPayed IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Thank you very much ... if I want to just select the ABC222 and ABC444 if you understand what I mean? To find the regnumbers that are in need of an update?

Comment: Is it the same for Microsoft Access Query?

Comment: @BarisTa yes, sometimes the MS-Access syntax is a little different, but this time is the same, is the Sold column NULL or empty? can you try to change `where sold is null` with `where sold=''` ?